Nomencl seems to be deleting some entries
I have the following in my nomenclature.tex:
\nomenclature[O1]{$| \cdot |$}{Absolute value of a scalar variable}
\nomenclature[O2]{$\| \cdot \|_2$}{Euclidean norm of a vector-valued variable}
\nomenclature[O3]{$\cdot \times \cdot$}{Vector cross product}
\nomenclature[O4]{$\left( \cdot \right)$}{Function argument}
\nomenclature[O5]{$\Delta$}{Difference operator}

all is good in the .nlo file, but in the .nls the first two entries are gone:
\begin{thenomenclature} 
\nomgroup{O}
  \item [{$\cdot \times \cdot$}]\begingroup Vector cross product\nomeqref {0}\nompageref{x}
  \item [{$\left( \cdot \right)$}]\begingroup Function argument\nomeqref {0}\nompageref{x}
  \item [{$\Delta$}]\begingroup Difference operator\nomeqref {0}\nompageref{x}

\end{thenomenclature}

In a bigger document I have even more entries, and still those 2 are the only 2 missing.
Is there something wrong in the formatting of those two entries?
I have deleted the .nlo and .nls multiple times and re-run the pdflatex-> makeindex ->pdflatex x2 chain, and the result is always the same.
If it matters, I am using VSCode and  the solution given here

Please, make a full compilable example.

| is a special character for nomencl (for MakeIndex, actually). In order to use it in a \nomenclature entry it should be quoted, but unfortunately the maintainers of nomencl chose % as the quote character, which makes it impossible to use it for its purpose.
On the other hand, |\cdot| is not the best idea for “unnamed argument”.
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\blank}{{{}\cdot{}}}

\begin{document}

Test

\nomenclature[O1]{$\lvert\blank\rvert$}{Absolute value of a scalar variable}
\nomenclature[O2]{$\lVert\blank\rVert_2$}{Euclidean norm of a vector-valued variable}
\nomenclature[O3]{$\blank\times\blank$}{Vector cross product}
\nomenclature[O4]{$(\blank)$}{Function argument}
\nomenclature[O5]{$\Delta$}{Difference operator}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}


Note that |\cdot|, \|\cdot\| and \cdot\times\cdot produce the same result as \lvert\blank\lvert, \lVert\blank\lVert and \blank\times\blank, but by pure chance. The output of (\cdot) is really wrong: (left is (\blank), right is (\cdot)

Note that \left and \right do nothing at all in this case except (they may actually introduce unwanted space).
